# Natural Language Processing Database Querying

Tags: javascript, python, json, nlp, nltk

I need to develop natural language querying tool for a structured database. I tried two approaches.

- using Python nltk (Natural Language Toolkit for python) using
- Javascript and JSON (for data source)

In the first case I did some NLP steps to format the natural query by doing removing stop words, stemming, finally mapping keywords using featured grammar mapping. This methodology works for simple scenarios.

Then I moved to second approach. Finding the data in JSON and getting corresponding column name and table name , then building a sql query. For this one,  I also implemented removing stop words, stemming using javascript.

Both of these techniques have limitations.I want to implement semantic search approach.

Please can anyone suggest me better approach to do this..

Comment: Could you be more clear about which are your goals? Do you mean something that parses a human sentence into a database query?

Comment: Yes i want to parse a human sentence into a database query..

Comment: I think you should provide some examples and some code, and also explain what these limitations are

Comment: First method is done using http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html

Comment: This can achieve only simple queries

Answer (score 1):

Semantic parsing for NLIDB (natural language interface to data bases) is a very evolved domain with many techniques: rule based methods (involving grammars) or machine learning techniques. They cover a large range of query inputs, and offer much more results than pure NL processing or regex methods.

The technique I favor is based on Feature based context-free grammars [FCFG](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnlp%5D%20fcfg). For starters, in the NTLK book [available online](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html), look for the string "sql0.fcfg". The code example shows how to map the NL phrase structure query "What cities are located in China" into an SQL query "SELECT City FROM city_table WHERE Country="china" via the feature "SEM" or semantics of the FCFG.

I recommend Covington's books

- NLP for Prloog Programmers (1994)
- Prolog Programming in Depth (1997)

They will help You go a long way. These PDF's are downloadable from his [site](http://www.covingtoninnovations.com/books.html).

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I think you should add some code, since not everyone has read the book.

Anyway my conclusion is that yes, as you said it has a lot of limitations and the only way to achieve more complex queries is to write very extensive and complete grammar productions, a pretty hard work.

Comment: Agree with Alex. Thankz for feedback

Comment: An answer with "yes, but it's hard" and "add some code to your question" is not an answer. Downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

More modern answer is that we will need to use a large language model, such as https://openai.com or https://text-generator.io
One trained on text and SQL, then a prompt e.g.
https://text-generator.io/use-cases/sql-code-generation

Be careful when processing the outputs of what it returns, it may be wrong in various ways and would need sanitization, also the prompt given needs the column/table names to know how to query the database and perhaps other examples of similar queries.

For validation, you might have to build validations similar to what an ide does like automatically fix the syntax e.g. any closing braces missed  for example